# showing each category separately

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to show my wordpress site each posts category seprately by using wordpress rest Api

i tried this `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?world`

but everytime it does not get filter just shows all post on website

my categories are as follow
[image: wordpress posts categories]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://jeremyjon.es/code/taxonomy-queries-with-wordpress-v2-rest-api/. In short, I think you don't need to append the term name (World), but the taxonomy name and the term id.

Comment: Hey Michael 
                  Thank you for quick reply it really did help me
I also want to know how to retrieve a page through wordpress rest Api
Regards Ahmed

Comment: Hmm, just a guess: `/page/pagename`?